# django admin actions vs save in model class

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I have a boolean field in my model indicating, that email with some info to the user was sent.
When I update it in admin I use `save()` method from the model, and there actually the email is being sent. And this works.

BUT:

When I try to use my actions defined like this:

```
def send_this_email(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(mail_sent=True)
send_this_email.short_description = "Send email with access data"
```

and in admin class:

```
actions = [send_this_email]
```

The method `save()` seems not being executed and email is not sent. How can I force my `send_this_email` to execute save?

If it matters I am using grappeli for my django admin.

Comment: But where is the code that sends the email?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is in save() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's documentation specifies that calling update() on a queryset will not call save or invoke any pre-/post-save hooks. I suggest you call the function explicitly when the email needs to get sent.

Alternatively, you can call save() in the admin function, but then you lose the benefits of the update() method.

Comment: how can I then execute it? Should I iterate over queryster and invoke method? Have tried. Not working.

Comment: Yes, that should work. What happens when you iterate over the objects in the queryset?

Comment: yeah partially. Now I do not know how to refer to previous value.

Comment: If you want to update your question to include more details about the current problem, I'm happy to take another look.